# Moshi @Json annotation not working for com.github.kittinunf.fuel.moshi.moshiDeserializerOf?

Tags: kotlin, moshi, kotlin-fuel

I have a ResponseObject:

```
data class ResponseObject(
        val notCamelcase: String,
        val param2: String,
        val param3: String
)
```

please notice the first parameter is not camelcase (like `notCamelCase`) in the response JSON body.

Furtheron, I trigger the REST call [with the FUEL library](https://github.com/kittinunf/fuel):

```
Fuel.get(someParam)
        .responseObject(moshiDeserializerOf(ResponseObject::class.java)) { _, response, result ->
            try {
                if (response.statusCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    val responseObject = result.component1()
        }
```

And following are my imports:

```
import com.github.kittinunf.fuel.Fuel
import com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.FuelError
import com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.FuelManager
import com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.HttpException
import com.github.kittinunf.fuel.moshi.moshiDeserializerOf
```

To use camelcase in my following code I modified the ResponseObject like:

```
data class ResponseObject(
        @Json(name="notCamelcase")
        val notCamelCase: String,
        val param2: String,
        val param3: String
)
```

as it [is described here....](https://github.com/square/moshi#custom-field-names-with-json)

In this case, `notCamelCase` is null. **Is the @Json not working with the com.github.kittinunf.fuel.moshi.moshiDeserializerOf only? Whats wrong?**

Comment: Please use the reflective KotlinJsonAdapterFactory or codegen when using Kotlin. The next version of Moshi will require them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `@field:Json()` annotation for Moshi kotlin.

```
data class ResponseObject(
    @field:Json(name="notCamelcase")
    val notCamelCase: String,
    val param2: String,
    val param3: String
)
```

Reference: https://github.com/square/moshi/issues/315
As mentioned in the discussion, this is still a workaround. The official Kotlin support is the proper way to go: https://github.com/square/moshi#kotlin

Comment: This is workaround. If you're using Kotlin with Moshi, use the official Kotlin support. The next version of Moshi will require it.

Comment: Thanks, @EricCochran. I expanded on the current state instead of just linking the related discussion.