# mapped data from json in kotlin shows wrong value

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to show this [data](https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=dhaka,bd&units=metric&appid=2dfe887bc005aa484dbb4d1bcb17deab) in my sample kotlin app.

I have created all appropriate models using moshi. Which can be found [here](https://github.com/fahimhoque/forecaster/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/forecaster/model/datamodel).

But the values are showing wrong. Even non null values are showing as null.

Example json, value in 0 index:

```
      "main": {
        "temp": 25.78,
        "feels_like": 25.95,
        "temp_min": 23.35,
        "temp_max": 25.78,
        "pressure": 1014,
        "sea_level": 1014,
        "grnd_level": 1012,
        "humidity": 59,
        "temp_kf": 2.43
      },
```

The model responsible:

```
@Parcelize
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class Main(

    @Json(name = "temp")
    val temp: Double?,
    @Json(name = "feels_like")
    val feelsLike: Double?,
    @Json(name = "temp_min")
    val tempMin: Double?,
    @Json(name = "temp_max")
    val tempMax: Double?,
    @Json(name = "pressure")
    val pressure: Double?,
    @Json(name = "sea_level")
    val seaLevel: Double?,
    @Json(name = "grnd_level")
    val grndLevel: Double?,
    @Json(name = "humidity")
    val humidity: Double?,
    @Json(name = "temp_kf")
    val tempKf: Double?,

) : Parcelable {

    fun getTempString(): String {
        return temp.toString().substringBefore(".") + "°"
    }

    fun getHumidityString(): String {
        return humidity.toString() + "°"
    }

    fun getTempMinString(): String {
        return tempMin.toString().substringBefore(".") + "°"
    }

    fun getTempMaxString(): String {
        return tempMax.toString().substringBefore(".") + "°"
    }
}
```

But when I print the main in 0 index shows:

```
Main(temp=298.26, feelsLike=null, tempMin=null, tempMax=null, pressure=1014.0, seaLevel=null, grndLevel=null, humidity=62.0, tempKf=null)
```

As a result the views are not working either.

The entire source code can be found [here](https://github.com/fahimhoque/forecaster).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See discussion [here](https://github.com/square/moshi/issues/315), it might be that the following anotation  `@field:Json(name = "temp_min")` instead of `@Json(name = "temp_min")`, and the same for the other members, could fix it. Alternatively, you can try to use a different version of Moshi. Also, see related discussion [Moshi @Json annotation not working for com.github.kittinunf.fuel.moshi.moshiDeserializerOf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56059579/moshi-json-annotation-not-working-for-com-github-kittinunf-fuel-moshi-moshidese)

Comment: yeah either the field name needs to be same, so underscore for underscore or `@field:Json`.